# Internet Explorer - Filter shadow property making inside text ugly

Tags: internet-explorer, text, css

I have a div with a box shadow in Internet Explorer (Internet Explorer 7  Internet Explorer 8) applied through following CSS.

```
box-shadow:        0px 0px 15px #FF00CC;
-o-box-shadow:     0px 0px 15px #FF00CC;
-moz-box-shadow:   0px 0px 15px #FF00CC;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #FF00CC;
zoom: 1;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ff99eb, Strength=7, Direction=0),
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ff99eb, Strength=7, Direction=90),
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ff99eb, Strength=7, Direction=180),
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ff99eb, Strength=7, Direction=270),
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color='#ffffff');
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border:1px solid #FF00CC;
```

It is giving it a box shadow, but making the inside text blurred and ugly, that is, black text is losing sharpness:

[image]

And without a box shadow properties it's like this:

[image]

How can I make the inside text normal besides giving the div a box shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be overcome in Internet Explorer 8 by wrapping in an extra div inside the content with `position:relative;` and the text again has its glory:

```
<div class="shadow-box">
    <div style="position:relative;">Lorem ipsum dosectetur adipisicing elit</div>
    </div>

    .shadow-box {
        box-shadow:        0px 0px 15px #FF00CC;
        -o-box-shadow:     0px 0px 15px #FF00CC;
        -moz-box-shadow:   0px 0px 15px #FF00CC;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #FF00CC;
        zoom: 1;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ff99eb, Strength=7, Direction=0),
                progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ff99eb, Strength=7, Direction=90),
                progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ff99eb, Strength=7, Direction=180),
                progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#ff99eb, Strength=7, Direction=270),
                progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color='#ffffff');
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        border:1px solid #FF00CC;
    }
```

But in Internet Explorer 7 if you use shadow filter it removes cleartype property on font ,and doesnt have any fix as per my search

Thanks to *[CSS Box Shadow](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)* and *[How to simulate CSS3 box-shadow in IE 6-8 without JavaScript.](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/)*.

Comment: Great answer, works well. But given that it requires a monumental amount of work I think i'll steer clear of ms filters for elements with text

Answer (score -1):

You can create an empty `div` with the shadow and move text from other element over it. You can use negative margin or absolute position.

Comment: i didnt know the length of inside text,its going to vary so,its height,to get text inside wrap of shadowed div will be turmoil

Comment: You can set `div`'s height by ECMAscript. It is weird solution, but I have no idea how to do it better.